# Text Fade Out / Read More Link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using a snippet I found from CSS Tricks but I'm having a little trouble editing the code to achieve what I have in mind.

Here is the article: https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

This works fine but I want the option for the user to close the expanded paragraph after they are done. So a 'Read Less or 'Close' function.

I'm using the following code

```
<script>
// DOM Ready
$(function() {

    var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;

    $(".sidebar-box .button").click(function() {

        // IE 7 doesn't even get this far. I didn't feel like dicking with it.

        totalHeight = 0

        $el = $(this);
        $p  = $el.parent();
        $up = $p.parent();
        $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");

        // measure how tall inside should be by adding together heights of all inside paragraphs (except read-more paragraph)
        $ps.each(function() {
            totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
            // FAIL totalHeight += $(this).css("margin-bottom");
        });

        $up
            .css({
            // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
            "height": $up.height(),
            "max-height": 9999
        })

            .animate({
            "height": totalHeight
        },500,function(){
            //Callback - after the animation is over
            jQuery('#masonry-content').masonry();
        });

        // fade out read-more
        $p.fadeOut();

        // prevent jump-down
        return false;

    });

});
```

At the bottom of the comments someone suggested using an update to acheive this functionality but that isn't working.

Here is a live example: http://www.cubadupa.co.nz/?post_type=marcato_artist

Any ideas? I'm new to javscript so sorry if this is a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make another button "Read Less" and attach an event with that button so that when it is clicked the event adjust the size of the parent div.
Check out this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/e2tjq27g/

This is the event executed when "Read less" button is clicked.

```
           $(".sidebar-box .read-less-button").click(function() {
                $el = $(this);
                $p  = $el.parent();
                $up = $p.parent();
                totalHeight = $up.height();
                $up.css({
                        "height": totalHeight,
                        "max-height": 9999
                    })
                    .animate({
                        "height": $orgHeight
                    });

                $p.fadeOut();
                $('.read-more').fadeIn();

                return false;

            });
```